# Converting variables between classes

Tags: c++, class

I have this structure of class and I don't know, why I got error. It's very hard too search a problem, because of error output.

```
error: cannot convert 'A::C*' to 'C*' in assignment: two = this;
```

How can I fix this error?

```
class B;
class C;

class A{
 class B{
   public:
   B* one
   C* two;
   And some methods....
   ...
 };
 class C : public B{
   public:
   int f;
   C(){
    two = this; //here is error
   }
 };
};
```

Comment: `class B;` isn't the same as `class A::B;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example declares 5 different classes (fully qualified, in order): `::B`, `::C`; `::A`, `::A::B` and `::A::C`, because in your code

```
class B;
class C;
```

declares `::B` and `::C` in the global namespace, which you probably didn't intend to. This lead the compiler to believe that the unqualified `C` in the `C* two;` field in `::A::B` refers to `::C` instead of `::A::C`.

Instead declare these classes inside `class A {}` like this:

```
class A{
 class B; // declares ::A::B
 class C; // declares ::A::C
 class B{
   public:
   B* one
   C* two; // ::A::C*
   And some methods....
   ...
 };
 class C : public B{
   public:
   int f;
   C(){
    two = this; // should work now
   }
 };
};
```

In the above the compiler now knows that by `C*` you mean `::A::C*` because when searching for a matching type for `C` it encounters the declaration of `class C;` in the inner scope of `class A {};`. However, it doesn't *"see"* the actual definition of `::A::C` declared below.

Detailed rules for unqualified name lookup can be found in section §3.4.1 of the C++ standard ([draft version](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual)).